# What is someone who makes a testimonial called?

Tags: word-choice

In the context of  advertising/marketing  a testimonial is:

> - Written recommendation from a celebrity or satisfied customer affirming the performance, quality, and/or value of a product or service. [Testimonials](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/testimonial.html) are one of the most potent tools of marketing. (Business dictionary.com)

What is the term used to refer to someone ( generally a celebrity) who makes a testimonial?

Comment: A witness is a person who offers testimony. A testimonial isn't the same thing, though.

Comment: I would suggest `a liar`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *endorser*. *Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines *[endorse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/a-straight-face?q=straight%20face)* as

> Declare one’s public approval or support of:
>   *the report was endorsed by the college*

Answer (score 1):

When a *pejorative* term is desired:

[**sellout**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sellout)

> Someone who does something that does not agree with that person's
>   beliefs or values especially in order to make money